# How to make a button print out certain text? - Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Below, I have created a code to track the laps a person who is running. At the moment, the button I had created tracks the laps and the time, but not on the GUI window. I was wondering how to make the data on the from the code show on the GUI window.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

laps=[0]
gui=Tk()
gui.geometry("200x100")
gui.title("lapping")

def afterbutton():
    label_1=Label(gui,text=end())

def end():
    end = time.time()
    elapsed = end - start
    laps[0]+=1
    print "%s seconds" % (elapsed)
    print "%s lap(s)" % (laps)

starting = raw_input("start? (s to start)")

if starting == "s":
    start = time.time()

button1=Button(gui,command=afterbutton,text="lap")
button1.grid()
button1.pack()

gui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the label at the same time you create the button.  You need to put it in the grid and pack it, just like you did with the button.  Then when the button is clicked, all you have to do is change the label's text.  This is what it looks like:

```
# python 3
from Tkinter import *
import time

laps=[0]
gui=Tk()
gui.geometry("200x100")
gui.title("lapping")

def end():
    end = time.time()
    elapsed = end - start
    laps[0] += 1
    s = "%s seconds %s laps" % (elapsed,laps)
    label1['text'] = s
    print("%s seconds" % (elapsed))
    print("%s lap(s)" % (laps))

starting = raw_input("start? (s to start)")

if starting == "s":
    start = time.time()

button1 = Button(gui, command=end, text="lap")
button1.grid()
button1.pack()
label1 = Label(gui)
label1.grid()
label1.pack()

gui.mainloop()
```

The function `afterbutton` is gone; all the work is done by `end()`.  I kept most of your program, but I'm using py3 so print is a function rather than a statement.  You'll have to fix that for py2. The text of the label is set by:

```
label1['text'] = s
```

which is a somewhat weird syntax when you first see it.

BTW, I don't see why you used a 1-element list for laps instead of a simple variable.